# How to manually fail a Spring Batch job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

This is something I need to do for testing purposes. I need a way to fail a Spring Batch job whenever I want based on certain preset conditions (such as number of items processed). However, I haven't been able to find anything like this so far.

I have found that Spring Batch has something like this -

```
<step id="step1" parent="s1" next="step2">

<step id="step2" parent="s2">
    <fail on="FAILED" exit-code="EARLY TERMINATION"/>
    <next on="*" to="step3"/>
</step>

<step id="step3" parent="s3">
```

But what I am looking for is something like this-

```
public void myJobFailingMethod()
 {
    if(conditionsMatch())
     {
        // fail the job 
     }  
 }
```

How to do this?

Update: The Job can be failed outside a step as well.

Comment: @maxhax I mean using a listener, in either the beforeStep or afterStep method.

Comment: in afterStep/beforeStep-method it should be enough to return ExitStatus.FAILED. or?

otherwise just throw an execption in a tasklet to force your step failing.

Comment: @maxhax Yup, that's what I am doing right now.

Comment: can't actually follow your situation. Where's your problem? What's happening? What should happen?

Comment: did you try to just throw an exception?

Comment: did it work? what do you miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void myJobFailingMethod()
{
    if(conditionsMatch())
    {
        throw new CustomJobFailingException(); // create this exception class.
                                               // It will fail the job.
    }  
}
```